# Change color of flask.flash messages

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to change the color of `flask.flash` messages? The message is currently written in black and in very small characters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Flask messages` takes optional argument called `category` and use this to update template as you like.

```
flash('This is error message', 'error')
```

And in your html do remember to add `with_categories` option

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% for category, message in messages %}
    <div class="{{ category }}">{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Also please include this in your stylesheet

```
.error {
    color: red
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks complicated for such a simple process :D

Comment: Its easy one. first do not concentrate on styling the error message.  If your flash message works then add the `flash('your_message', category="your_error_argument")` add the `with_categories=True` in template that's it.

Comment: For Flask 2.0.1, it seems like you need to specify flash('This is error message', category='error').  You can't just put flash('This is error message', 'error') because for some reason, it doesn't capture 'error' as the category.  Play around with whatever version of Flask you're using to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would simply be to just wrap the actual message in a paragraph

and not a list item element

i.e.: `<p>{{ message }}</p>`, where

is permissible; See illustration below.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>My Application</title>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```